# MatBlazor - Position of down arrow is not correct in MatNavMenu

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, matblazor

I am using MatBlazor for my Blazor Server Side project. I created MatNavMenu but in sub menu the positioning of arrow is not correct.

[image: Please see the positioning of arrow, it is a bit down not centered.]

Please see the positioning of arrow, it is a bit down not centered. Here is the code I am using

```
<MatNavMenu>
<MatNavSubMenu>
    <MatNavItem><MatIcon Icon="dashboard"></MatIcon>&nbsp; Dashboard</MatNavItem>
    <MatNavSubMenuHeader>
        <MatNavItem AllowSelection="false"><MatIcon Icon="location_city"></MatIcon>&nbsp; City Management</MatNavItem>
    </MatNavSubMenuHeader>
    <MatNavSubMenuList>
        <MatNavItem Href="#"><MatIcon Icon="list"></MatIcon>&nbsp; Cites</MatNavItem>
        <MatNavItem Href="/City/AddNew"><MatIcon Icon="add"></MatIcon>&nbsp; Add New</MatNavItem>
    </MatNavSubMenuList>
</MatNavSubMenu>
</MatNavMenu>
```

Any help will be highly appriciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the same problem and what is happening here is a style from another package is interfering in matblazor's style

As you can see in this gif, the problem is that another library is adding `line-height` to the body and making it go down a little.

[image]

To solve this you can reset the value with `line-height: normal;`

Comment: Which package was the problem. I wrote MatNavMenu for MatBlazor. Thanks for the insight on the issue!